# How to customize overlay of intro.js

Tags: tooltip, intro.js

I would like to customize the tooltip in intro.js .(Change the background color of tooltip to blue) Is it possible to achieve in intro.js

Answer (score 2):

1. `overlayOpacity` property Adjust the overlay opacity of backdrop created by intojs. The range is 0 to 1

   Add `overlayOpacity:0` in introJs options to completely remove the backdrop.
   `introJs().setOption("overlayOpacity", 0);`
2. override `.introjs-tooltip` class to change background of tooltip.

   `.introjs-tooltip{
     background-color:#0000FF;
   }`

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is adding a new CSS rule to override the `background-color` of `.introjs-overlay`:

```
.introjs-overlay {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Also you can add background gradient, opacity, whatever you want.

Comment: I'm adding this but not overriding! (Although I have tried to add "!important") By the way, when it overrides, does it hide old styles of this class? Or just add new style to near existing ones?

Comment: where do I use this class?